# vb.net sqlclient insert output

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommand

I have a ms sql table PRODUCTS.
And it has three columns ID (int),NAME (nvarchar),TSTAMP (timestamp)

I want to get new inserted row's both id and timestamp (like multiple select scope_identity).
I can achieve that in sql as following:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (NAME)
OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.TSTAMP
VALUES ('Example Product')
```

But how can i read it in vb.net with sqlclient.sqlcommad on insertation? Which function of sqlcommand do i have to use and how? ExecuteReader maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **ExecuteReader()** method of *SqlCommand* would work the same as with *SELECT*.

> OUTPUT clause works like a SELECT statement but its usage differs in
>   INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands

Here's a sample code. Try it.

```
Dim connString As String = "server=Test; database=Test;" + _
                           "uid=sa; pwd="
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)

Dim cmdString As String = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (NAME) " + _
                          "OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.TSTAMP " + _
                          "VALUES ('Example Product')"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdString, conn)
conn.Open()
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
conn.Close()
```

Here're some links

[Running The OUTPUT Clause From C#](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=46)

[Implementing the OUTPUT Clause in SQL Server 2008](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/implementing-the-output-clause-in-sql-server-2008/)